# Error:(165, 93) error: cannot find symbol class DynamicUtil

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

This error happens when I pack some codes of databinding in a "`baseFeature = true`" module.

I have already opened databinding V2 and experimental tool:

```
android.databinding.enableV2=true
android.enableExperimentalFeatureDatabinding=true
```

Current gradle plugin:

```
3.2.0-alpha0X
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
or
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.5-all.zip
```

[issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/73634828)